# How to make a <div> or <a href="#"> to align center

Tags: center

I'm using the following code in body section.

`<center><a href="contact.html" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a></center>`

Is there any alternative for `<center>` tag?

How can I make it center without using `<center>` tag?

Comment: Using css would be a better way

Answer (score 26):

Add `text-align:center;display:block;` to the css class.  Better than setting a style on the controls themselves.  If you want to change it you do so in one place.

Comment: I used
<a href="contact.html" style="margin:20px auto; text-align:center; display:block; width:120px;" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a>
 and its working.. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <a href="contact.html" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I used
<a href="contact.html" style="margin:20px auto; text-align:center; display:block; width:120px;" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a>
 and its working.. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use css like below;

```
 <a href="contact.html" style="margin:auto; text-align:center; display:block;" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a>
```

Comment: I used
<a href="contact.html" style="margin:20px auto; text-align:center; display:block; width:120px;" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a>
 and its working.. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

You can put in in a paragraph

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="contact.html" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a></p>
```

To align a div in the center, you have to do 2 things:
- Make the div a fixed width
- Set the left and right margin properties variable

```
<div class="container">
 <div style="width:100px; margin:0 auto;">
     <span>a centered div</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used
<a href="contact.html" style="margin:20px auto; text-align:center; display:block; width:120px;" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a>
 and its working.. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why but for me **`text-align:center;`** only works with:

```
text-align: grid;
```

OR

```
display: inline-grid;
```

I checked and no one style is overriding.

My structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>ElementToCenter</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below:

```
a {
display: block;
width: 113px;
margin: auto; 
}
```

By setting, in my case, the link to `display:block`, it is easier
to position the link.
This works the same when you use a `<div>` tag/class.
You can pick any `width` you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4 align="center"> 
              <a href="Demo2.html">Center</a>  
        </h4>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a handy  tag... whatever you put in between, gets centered.
Like so:

```
<center>
<a href..... whatever>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

display inline-block to make it fit width,
margin-left to make it move 50% away from left,
and transform translateX to make it center his position

```
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Answer (score -3):

In your html file:

```
<a href="contact.html" class="button large hpbottom">Get Started</a>
```

In your css file:

```
.hpbottom{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: `text-align:center` will only work on block-level elements, so it won't work on `<a>`.